# Need Help Converting Tweet Data to JSON text file

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I am working on a project where I need to query twitter api data. I am pretty new and am getting stuck writing all of the data into a json format text file.

I have a large file with a lot of missing twitter data. I am using the tweet ids in order to query data from the Twitter API. While my code is running I am able to see the tweet data populating the text file. However, after my code is done executing I have a blank document with data for a single tweet.

I believe the issue is probably with the way I am constructing my "with open" statements. However, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank You!

```
tweet_file = 'tweet_json.txt'
list_id = (twitter_archive['tweet_id'])
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), tweet_file), mode = 'w') as f:
    for id in list_id:
        try:
            tweet = api.get_status(id, tweet_mode='extended')
            json.dump(tweet._json, f, indent = 4)
            f.write('\n')
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            print("tweet # " + str(id) + " not found")
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), tweet_file), mode = 'w') as f: 
        json.dump(tweet._json, f, indent = 4)
```

Comment: _"after my code is done executing I have a blank document with data for a single tweet."_ Please clarify. Do you mean the file is completely blank and contains no data? Or do you mean the file contains data about exactly one tweet, even though you had many more tweets?

Comment: Thanks! @roganjosh. I know it was a really dumb question but thank you for helping me out. I knew it was a really simple fix.

Comment: @KevinNgo It's not a dumb question; hindsight is brilliant :) I was curious why you thought you needed it a second time - indentation is important and you were already in a context block from the first `with`

Comment: @roganjosh. In my lessons I haven't used "with" yet. I thought I needed a "closing statement" in order to execute the code correctly. I was wrong.

I appreciate your help. It can be a little intimidating posting on stackoverflow as a student.

Comment: Well, I would answer but now I'm doubting myself in how I explain why your approach didn't work so you're not alone :)

Comment: Go ahead. What you said solved my issue. I can then mark the answer solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file in "w" mode truncates the file, erasing anything that was in it previously.

When you open your file the second time, it erases everything you wrote to the file inside the for loop. It then writes the contents of the `tweet` object to the file. This is why you only see one tweet in your output.

`with` blocks do not require any sort of closing statement. This is typical of block structures in Python. The `with` block will perform its cleanup on its own when the program exits the indented section.

If you delete the last two lines of your program, then all of the tweets should properly appear in your output file.